# Escaping erb tags in grunt

Tags: javascript, node.js, gruntjs

I want to regex-replace a string using the grunt-regex-replace module. Something like this:

```
{
    name: 'Change the path name',
    search: /src="app.js"/g,
    replace: 'src="<%= path_to_file %>app.js"'
}
```

The location it's regex-ing on is a .html.erb file, hence the <%= %> tags.

Unfortunately, grunt for some reason doesn't pass the <%= %> tags through -- the result is

```
src="app.js"
```

Does anyone know how to escape these in Grunt so they output as they should? The desired result is

```
src="<%= path_to_file %>app.js"
```

Does Grunt use a templating language like EJS that uses those tags semantically? If so, how to escape?

Comment: first of all, are you sure the regex is even matching?

Comment: Yes. I can change the replace to something else and it will replace.